# Nested model Routes design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, nested

I have a User , Boat and Picture model. `User has_many :boats`, boat `belongs_to :user`. Also Boat `has_many :pictures`, picture `belongs_to :boat`, pretty clear.

My problem is, I did not nest the routes of with User and Boat model, so when user clicks to add new boat link, the url becomes `...boats/new.2` (2 as a user with id = 2). So now that I have picture model where boat owner can upload pictures. I do not know how i can create those pictures. I am having troubles to retrieve boat id.

When I write `<%= link_to "New Picture",  pictures_new_path(current_user) %>`
url becomes `...pictures/new.2`. It seems it will save to user with id 2. That is why `Boat.last.pictures.last.name` for instance return `nil`. I could not get boat id at `#create` action either.

Here is `#create`

```
def create
    @boat = Boat.find(params[:id]) #Here does not work, can't get boat id
    @picture = Picture.new(picture_params) if logged_in?
    if @picture.save
      #flash[:success] = "Continue from here"
      render 'show'
    else
      render 'new' 
    end
  end
```

So should i change `<%= link_to "New Picture",  pictures_new_path(current_user) %>` somehow to get boat id, or nest the routes. I am confused.

EDIT:

Here is my User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :boats, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Here is Boat Model

```
class Boat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :pictures
end
```

Here is Picture Model

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :boat
end
```

I also can not reach to pictures from boat. such; `Boat.last.pictures.last.name`
gives an error, it does not see the table column name. But when I write `Picture.last.name`. It works. I think there is a problem with associations. But everything seems fine.

here `boat_id` is `nil`.

```
> Boat.last
  Boat Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "boats".* FROM "boats"  ORDER BY "boats"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Boat id: 92, model: "LAGOON HERON 15C/FO [15']", year: "2004", brand: "A & M Manufacturing Inc", created_at: "2015-04-19 20:27:21", updated_at: "2015-04-19 20:27:21", user_id: 2, captained: nil, boat_type: "Power", daily_price: nil, boat_length: nil, listing_tagline: nil, listing_description: nil, boat_category: nil, hull_material: nil, mast_material: nil> 

> Picture.last
  Picture Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "pictures".* FROM "pictures"  ORDER BY "pictures"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Picture id: 5, name: "Something!", created_at: "2015-04-19 20:35:38", updated_at: "2015-04-19 20:35:38", boat_id: nil>
```

here also `boat_id` is `nil`.

```
> Boat.last.pictures.last
  Boat Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "boats".* FROM "boats"  ORDER BY "boats"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  Picture Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "pictures".* FROM "pictures" WHERE "pictures"."boat_id" = ?  ORDER BY "pictures"."id" DESC LIMIT 1  [["boat_id", 93]]
 => nil
```

EDIT 2:

Here is `routes.rb`

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
      get 'pictures/new'
      get 'pictures/show'
      get 'pictures/edit'
      post 'pictures/create'

      get 'boats/update_years', :as => 'update_years'
      get 'boats/update_models', :as => 'update_models'
      get 'boats/new'
      resources :boats,               only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
      resources :users
    ......
    end
```

EDIT 3:

And I get this error. I think the association is wrong somehow

```
> Boat.last.pictures.last.name
  Boat Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "boats".* FROM "boats"  ORDER BY "boats"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  Picture Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "pictures".* FROM "pictures" WHERE "pictures"."boat_id" = ?  ORDER BY "pictures"."id" DESC LIMIT 1  [["boat_id", 93]]
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

EDIT 4:

OK. I solve the problem of associations by destroying picture model and creating new one. But i still do not know how I can reach to Boat id.

Comment: It looks like you're using current_user instead of a value(id) for an existing boat object, which is why you can't get a result for @boat. There isn't enough details to here offer a full answer.

Comment: Yes, because I could not figure it out how I can get the boat id. What would you like to learn?. I ll edit the question

Comment: show your `config/routes.rb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your routes to:

```
    resources :users
    resources :boats, except: :destroy do
      get 'update_years'
      get 'update_models'
      resources: :pictures
    end
```

And you could also add the whole `resources :boats`-tag into the a do-end-block for the user resources.